# C# RadioButtonList into TableCells

Tags: c#, webforms, controller, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to add radio buttons to my Table.

The problem is that I'm using a RadioButtonList to hold radios and an ListItem cant be added to a cell for some reason? Is my code totally of or is there another way to handle this in .net?

```
private TableRow generateCells(String domainName)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();

            Label dName = new Label();
            dName.Text = domainName; 

            RadioButtonList radioList = new RadioButtonList();

            ListItem sunriseA = new ListItem();
            sunriseA.Value = Price_Types.SUNRISE_ONE.ToString();            
            radioList.Items.Add(sunriseA);

            ListItem sunriseB = new ListItem();
            sunriseB.Value = Price_Types.SUNRISE_TWO.ToString();
            radioList.Items.Add(sunriseB);

            ListItem landrush = new ListItem();
            landrush.Value = Price_Types.LANDRUSH.ToString();
            radioList.Items.Add(landrush);

            ListItem general = new ListItem();
            general.Value = Price_Types.GENERAL.ToString();
            radioList.Items.Add(general);

            row.Cells.Add(addCell(dName));
            // this is not working
            row.Cells.Add(addCell(sunriseA));
            row.Cells.Add(addCell(sunriseB));
            row.Cells.Add(addCell(landrush));
            row.Cells.Add(addCell(general));

            return row;

        }

        private TableCell addCell(Control c)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Controls.Add(c);
            return cell;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ListItem belongs directly in a RadioButtonList (or some other ASP.Net list control). You could try to use plain [HtmlInputRadioButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputradiobutton.aspx) with a specified [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputradiobutton.name.aspx) to link them together.